# PHP create an array with values that equal true

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have passed a series of parameters from a jQuery file to a PHP script for processing.

Some of the parameters include names, email, department, etc. The majority of the parameters will either be TRUE or FALSE.

I want to build an array to include all of the parameters that equal TRUE.

```
<?php
  $value = $_POST['criteria'];

 $firstname = $value['firstname'];
 $email = $value['email'];
 $department = $value['department'];

 $parameter1 = $value['parameter1']; // equals TRUE
 $parameter2 = $value['parameter2']; // equals FALSE
 $parameter3 = $value['parameter3']; // equals TRUE
 $parameter4 = $value['parameter4']; // equals TRUE

?>
```

So the results of the array I want to produce should look like this:

```
$array = ['parameter1', 'parameter3', 'parameter4'];
```

I know I must use a loop, but I am not exactly sure how to start it.

### Edit

Here is where I create the variable criteria in jQuery, starting with a button click event:

```
$('#requestAppSubmit').on('click', function()
{
  var criteria = 
  {
    firstname: $('#firstname').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    department: $('#department').val(),
    // the next parameters check if a checkbox was checked
    parameter1: $('#dashboard').is(':checked'),
    parameter2: $('#schedules').is(':checked'),
    parameter3: $('#finance').is(':checked'),
    parameter4: $('#businessplan').is(':checked'),
    // quite a few more parameters
  }

  // then I use a ajax post
  $.post('process/editRep.php', {criteria:criteria}, function(data)
  {
    console.log(data);
   //
  });
});
```

At this point, using your suggestions below, the most I can output is this:

```
Array()
```

Comment: You want an array of indexes where the value is true?

Comment: Yes, if the parameter is TRUE, then add it to an array.

Comment: These values come from `$_POST['criteria']`? So are they actually strings "TRUE" and "FALSE"?

Comment: You should really call the parameters differently. If someone else was to read your code, he'll hate you. Why don't you call parameter1 dashbord, parameter2 schedules, ... and so on like you did in the HTML? That's really a lot better and helps to understand your code.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - I just included the JQuery.  I am assuming the values TRUE/FALSE values are passed as strings.

Comment: @maio290 - Understood.

Comment: @JohnBeasley whenever in doubt, `var_dump($_POST)` :)

Comment: Also, the output `Array()` is what you get when you try to `echo` an array. It's the generic string representation of an array in PHP. In order to output an array of strings, you'll need to iterate it and echo the individual items.

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone who contributed to my post.  I accepted @Syscall answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) to keep only boolean values, and then, use [`array_keys()`](https://php.net/array_keys) to get the names:

```
$value = [
    'firstname'=>'foo',
    'email'=>'bar',
    'department'=>'baz',
    'parameter1'=>true,
    'parameter2'=>false,
    'parameter3'=>true,
    'parameter4'=>true
];

$array = array_filter($value, function($item) {
    return $item === true;
});
$array = array_keys($array);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => parameter1
    [1] => parameter3
    [2] => parameter4
)
```

If values are not booleans, you could also use :

```
$array = array_filter($value, function($item) {
    return is_numeric($item) && $item == true;
});
```

This will work with `'0'` and `'1'`.

Comment: One possible issue, according to the OP code it looks like the array comes from `$_POST` originally. So all the values will be strings, right?

Comment: Right @Don'tPanic That's why I've updated the answer with `is_numeric()`. Thanks!

Comment: I think that is the problem I'm having.  The TRUE/FALSE values are being passed as strings, from the JQuery.

Comment: Please @JohnBeasley , See updated answer (last part). This will work with  '1' and '0'.

Comment: I'd suggest just explicitly comparing to "TRUE" in the callback

Comment: Right again @Don'tPanic! Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohnBeasley Did you check with the last part of the anwer (with `is_numeric()`)?

Comment: @Syscall - Yes, I did see is_numeric part of your answer.  However, I am only producing the following results:  Array()  which is an actually an upgrade from the original results: Array

Comment: @Syscall - so I changed "return $item === true" to "return $item == 'true'" and I was able to achieve the results I needed.  Not sure if you want to edit your answer, but I will mark your answer as what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop at all, just two functions: array_filter to filter out the false values, and array_keys to get the keys:

```
$array = array_keys(array_filter($values));

// results = ['parameter1', 'parameter3', 'parameter4']
```

Comment: I think this will return also the strings "firstname", "email", ... from `$values`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `foreach`:

```
foreach($value as $index => $bool){
    if($bool){
        $new_array[] = $index;
    }
}
```

Will only work if your values are of `bool` type and not `string`

If they are strings just compare them using `==`

Answer (score 1):

I can guess from your question that you need to process a list of parameters you care what their contents are like name, department and email, as well as a boolean list of attributes, in the same POST request.

I would encapsulate all the boolean attributes you need to pass in an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[parameter1]"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[parameter2]"/>
...
```

and process it in PHP:

```
<?php
    $options = $_POST['options'] ?? [];
    $onlyTrueOptions = array();
    foreach($options as $optionName => $value) {
        if($value) // or another desidered comparison
            $onlyTrueOptions[] = $optionName;
    }
```

Comment: I agree it's a good idea to separate the options from the other input. It's not certain that they come from form inputs, though.

Answer (score 0):

Never, really never use "static-incremented" variables. That's what you use arrays for.

```
$arr = array();

for($i = 1; $i<=4; $i++)
{
    if(strcmp($value['parameter'.$i],"TRUE") === 0)
    {
        array_push($arr,"parameter$i");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is off topic, but what do you mean "static-incremented" variables? Do you mean specifically for arrays?

Comment: I mean stuff like that:

$language1 = "German";
$language2 = "English";
$language3 = "French"; 

instead of 

$languages = {"German","English","French"};